# looking for computer readable lists of CVE to package name sources

Tags: windows, linux, cve, automation, package-manager

Redhat has a very nice xml containing all known CVEs and the package version they are fixed in (https://www.redhat.com/security/data/metrics/rpm-to-cve.xml).

I would like to know if any other Linux distro (or even Windows) has something equivalent to that?

I've found several places where you can manually search for a package name or cve but what I am looking for is formatted data fitting for automated systems to consume. Regularly updated DBs or formatted files would make it much easier in the long run for large systems.

The problems with reference tables like: http://cve.mitre.org/data/refs/refmap/source-MS.html
Are that:
A) Its not in a computer readable format, requiring unreliable crawling.
B) It only points to the advisory in the relevant distro, it does not directly contain in which packages the CVE was fixed in. Requiring additional crawling of unstructured data.

what I'm asking if there is any source for the data directly.

Comment: What individual distros do is up to the distros (that makes this more of a Linux question than a security one). There is a CVE to KB reference map: http://cve.mitre.org/data/refs/refmap/source-MS.html

Comment: I hear you that you are looking for this data in a particular format, but this question would still be off topic just as the duplicate I linked to was off topic. I linked to that other question and the reference map as a way of getting you part way to your goal.

Comment: So, I ran the search that I recommended in the duplicate question, and I still get https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36982 as a top hit.

Comment: and this: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/main.html